# How to use a decimal separator other than a period in TAdvStringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I am able to insert numbers separated by a dot in a `TAdvStringGrid` such as 1.6 by double clicking it but I am not able to enter it as 1,6. Is there a way to enter numbers separated by comma to be displayed in `TAdvStringGrid`?

Comment: From the manual: *For all floating-point formats, the actual characters used as decimal and thousand separators are
obtained from the DecimalSeparator and ThousandSeparator global variables or their
TFormatSettings equivalent.*